# How to append increment numbers to Slug using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose on a nodejs project. In it, what I want to do is, when I save "slug" into db, I want to check if slug already exists then add a counter to it before storing. So something like this
my-title
my-title-2
my-title-3
...

I have created below express middleware code which checks the given slug and does the checking and adds counter to it. I found it from stackoverflow post but I think this only work upto my-title-2. If you add one more "my-title" slug, then it goes into infinite recursion calls. Below is the code:

```
module.exports.generateSlug = (req, res, next) => {
    // remove special chars, trim spaces, replace all spaces to dashes, lowercase everything
    var slug = req.body.slug
        .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "")
        .trim()
        .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
        .toLowerCase();
    var counter = 2;

    // check if there is existing release with same slug
    Release.findOne({ slug: slug }, checkSlug);

    // recursive function for checking repetitively
    function checkSlug(err, existingRelease) {
        if (existingRelease) {
            // if there is release with the same slug
            if (counter == 2)
                // if first round, append '-2'
                slug = slug.concat("-" + counter++);
            // increment counter on slug (eg: '-2' becomes '-3')
            else slug = slug.replace(new RegExp(counter++ + "$", "g"), counter);
            Release.findOne({ slug: slug }, checkSlug); // check again with the new slug
        } else {
            // else the slug is set
            req.body.slug = slug;
            next();
        }
    }
};
```

I think the error is in this line

```
slug = slug.replace(new RegExp(counter++ + "$", "g"), counter);
```

Comment: No matter how you do this, unless the slug field is somehow defined to be unique in the database (e.g. with an UNIQUE index in SQL; not sure what the MongoDB analogue is), this is prone to race conditions and as such, collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out by myself. Below is the code :)

```
module.exports.generateSlug = (req, res, next) => {
  var slug = req.body.slug
          .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "")
          .trim()
          .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
          .toLowerCase();

  // check if there is existing release with same slug
  Release.find({ slug: new RegExp("^" + slug, "i") }, (err, results) => {
    if (results == null) {
      next();
    } else {
      var count = results.length + 1;
      req.body.slug = `${slug}-${count}`;
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This will unnecessarily fetch all results from the database, and it won't work correctly if you have e.g. `foo`, `foobar`, `fooquux` in the database and your `req.body.slug` is `foo`.

Comment: If in your db, you have `slug` and `slug-3` then your code will create duplicate `slug-3`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc yeah I just noticed that. This is really painful to implement

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive reformulation using async functions.

I'll reiterate what I said in the comments, though:

> No matter how you do this, unless the slug field is somehow defined to be unique in the database (e.g. with an UNIQUE index in SQL; not sure what the MongoDB analogue is), this is prone to race conditions and as such, collisions.

```
/**
 * Find a free slug (or other value) by appending a counter to the given prefix and passing it
 * to the given `func` function, which should return a promise with a falsy value if the slug is free.
 * @param prefix Prefix for attempts.
 * @param func Predicate function.
 * @param maxAttempts Maximum number of attempts.
 * @returns {Promise<string|*>}
 */
async function findFreeSlug(prefix, func, maxAttempts = 10) {
  for (let i = 1; i < maxAttempts; i++) {
    const slug = i > 1 ? `${prefix}-${i}` : prefix;
    const result = await func(slug);
    if (!result) {
      return slug;
    }
  }
  throw new Error(
    `Could not find a free slug for ${prefix} after ${maxAttempts} attempts`,
  );
}

/**
 * Return a promise that returns true if a Release with the given slug exists.
 * @param slug
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
async function doesReleaseWithSlugExist(slug) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Release.findOne({ slug }, (err, release) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(!!release);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.generateSlug = async (req, res, next) => {
  // remove special chars, trim spaces, replace all spaces to dashes, lowercase everything
  const initialSlug = req.body.slug
    .replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "")
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, "-")
    .toLowerCase();

  req.body.slug = await findFreeSlug(initialSlug, doesReleaseWithSlugExist);
  next();
};
```